# Exporting/importing Json object in es6

Tags: javascript, json

I am converting some ES5 code to ES6.

I have the following line somewhere in the file `StatesComponent.js`

```
const STATES = require('../data/states.js');
```

I am using jspm and it doesn't support `require`, so I would like to use ES6 `import` syntax instead.

The `states.js` file contains the following:

```
exports.AU = [
    { value: 'australian-capital-territory', label: 'Australian Capital Territory', className: 'State-ACT' },
    { value: 'new-south-wales', label: 'New South Wales', className: 'State-NSW' },
    { value: 'victoria', label: 'Victoria', className: 'State-Vic' },

];

exports.US = [
    { value: 'AL', label: 'Alabama', disabled: true },
    { value: 'AK', label: 'Alaska' },
    { value: 'AS', label: 'American Samoa' },
];
```

`STATES` variable is being used as `var options = STATES[this.state.country];`

How do I change the format of the json in `states.js` such that I can `import' it?

i.e `import STATES from '../data/states'`

Comment: Try `import * as STATES from '../data/states.js'`;

Comment: Just for your information: This is not JSON. These are JavaScript literal objects.

Answer (score 57):

Not sure if you got the answer to this already but you can export it as:-

```
export default {
  STATES: {
    'AU' : {...},
    'US' : {...}
  }
};
```

to which you can import as:-

```
import STATES from 'states';
```

or

```
var STATES = {};
STATES.AU = {...};
STATES.US = {...};
export STATES;
```

to which you can import as:-

```
import { STATES } from 'states';
```

Notice the difference between one that uses `default` and one that doesn't. With `default` you can export any javascript expression and during import you can use whatever identifier and it will be defaulted to that `default` expression.
You could also have done

```
import whatever from 'states';
```

and `whatever` would get the value of an object that we assigned to default.

In contrast, when you don't export `default` expression, `export` exports it as an part of object which is why you had to use

```
import {STATES}
```

In this case you *HAVE* to use the right literal name for import to work or else import will not be able to understand what you're trying to import. Also, note that it's using [`object destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to import the right value.

And like @AlexanderT said, there are ways to import as `*` too, in fact there are various ways to [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) but I hope I explained the core concept of how this `import/export` works.